# Multi-level dropdown list, Qt

Tags: c++, qt, dropdownbox

I am trying to make a multi-level drop-down list in Qt ? I tried to use a ComboBox, but I think it is only for making a single-level drop-down list.

Answer (score -1):

Try using [`QMenu`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmenu.html). It is possible to add [submenus](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmenu.html#addMenu).